# How to send "--noprofile" or "--norc" to bash with putty (on Windows)

Tags: bash, login, putty

How can I disable `.bashrc` and `.profile` when I log in to linux with putty from Windows ?
(On *nix: `ssh hostname "bash --norc --profile"`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to execute a remote command rather than login and start a shell.

Connection > SSH

Remote Command:
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc